# Add multiple pictures into firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I know this question has been asked a lot. But literally non of the answers work for me.
My problem is the images appeared to be saved but on firebase but unfortunately they are the same name so firebase deletes the old one and a inserts a new one. I have done everything i can do to change the name but I can't find a way.

Here is my code for uploading!

```
private void Fileuploader() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String imageid;
        imageid = arabic.getText().toString()+"-"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"."+"jpg";
        String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("storeid");
        member.setImageid(imageid);
        reference.child(id).child(arname).setValue(member);
        progress.showProgress(profuctadd.this,"Loading...",false);
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(profuctadd.this);
        Cursor getimage = databaseHelper.GetPath();
        while (getimage.moveToNext()){
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getimage.getString(0));
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 35, out);
            byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
            System.out.println("IMAGES UPLOADEDDDD: "+ data);
            StorageReference Ref = mStorageRef.child(imageid);

            Ref.putBytes(data)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                            //Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            //Toast.makeText(profuctadd.this,"Image uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progress.hideProgress();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(profuctadd.this,showProducts.class);
                            intent.putExtra("spec",getIntent().getStringExtra("spec"));
                            intent.putExtra("storeid",getIntent().getStringExtra("storeid"));
                            startActivity(intent);
                            DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(profuctadd.this);
                            Cursor cursor2 = mDatabaseHelper.DeleteDataOfTableImagesAr();
                            cursor2.moveToNext();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                            // ...
                            Toast.makeText(profuctadd.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

        }





    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only calculating `imageid` once across all images, so each image will have the same name. You'll want to calculate a new value for each image, and probably also throw in a counter just to make sure they're all unique:

```
private void Fileuploader() throws FileNotFoundException {
    String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("storeid");
    member.setImageid(imageid);
    reference.child(id).child(arname).setValue(member);
    progress.showProgress(profuctadd.this,"Loading...",false);
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(profuctadd.this);
    Cursor getimage = databaseHelper.GetPath();
    int count = 0;
    while (getimage.moveToNext()){
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getimage.getString(0));
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 35, out);
        byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
        System.out.println("IMAGES UPLOADEDDDD: "+ data);
        StorageReference Ref = mStorageRef.child(imageid);

        String imageid = arabic.getText().toString()+"-"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"_"+(count++)+"."+"jpg";
        Ref.putBytes(data)
        ...
```